# Get value from array couses "Property 'value' does not exist on type"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to pull out the data from array images. In ImageValue i have two strings: symbol and imageType. Why i get this error about property 'value'.

**Error**

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'ImageValue'

**Array with data**

[image]

**Component**

```
this.props.images.filter((image) =>
   image.value.symbol.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchSymbol.toLowerCase())
).map(image => (
    table.push(
       <div>{image.value.symbol + "." + image.value.imageType}</div>
    )
));
```

**ImageValue**

```
 class ImageValue {
    symbol: string;
    imageType: string;
}
```

Comment: `ImageValue` does not have a property called `value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you have mistaken typing the `ImageValue`:

```
type ImageValueType {
    value: { 
      symbol: string;
      imageType: string;
    }
}
```